# Remix IDE nolonger loads old solidity compilers. Error: "mock compiler: source not found|

Tags: solidity, remix, compiler, ide

The Ethereum solidity Remix IDE doesn't work for some reason.

It doesn't seem to load the various compiler versions and renders the error:

[image]

`mock compiler: source not found`

I've tried to install `remix-ide` , the special `npm` package but I still can't find the old solidity compilers in the Setting drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue being tracked at https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/issues/990.

Remix is trying to reach out to another server (https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/list.json) to display possible versions of solidity, but that server is not responding.

For now you could use this older version of Remix: https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity.