# Where is web3.eth.abi with the version of web3.js given with Metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask, the-dao

Seems the docs doesn’t contain the answer. Looks like that part was moved elsewhere with latest transaction.
The aim is to access encodeFunctionSignature() for knowing to which function name the selector `82661dc4` belongs to in [theᴅᴀᴏ contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413#code).

Comment: Why the downvote ? This is an ᴀᴘɪ question.

Comment: Since Metamask is a plugin it is problematic for them to provide an web3 version. If it is too new it might contains bugs, if it is too old it might not work with some apps. So they decided that you do not have to rely on the web3 version included with Metamask but to use your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lookup 82661dc4 via the 4byte.directory:
See here: https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x82661dc4

web3.eth.abi is part of web3.js 1.2.x, while Metamask uses web3.js 0.2.x
See this link on how to use web3.js 1.2.1 with metamask: 
[problem connecting web3 v 1.2.1 with metamask : 'currentProvider' of undefined](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73846/problem-connecting-web3-v-1-2-1-with-metamask-currentprovider-of-undefined)

Comment: You see the problem was this one : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/55537